# Indentation error on line 32 with my if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm struggling to find out why I get an indent error in my code. I've tried getting rid of tabs, and adding them. I've only used tabs: no spaces were used.

Here is a link:
https://repl.it/@OwenLagger1/SameReflectingCoderesource#main.py

Thanks for any help

P.S.
Sorry I have a link instead of code

Comment: You get the indentation error because that `if` statement is indented relative to the previous statement, yet that previous statement wasn't anything that starts a new indented block.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't convert everything to tabs but to spaces. To cite the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces): "Spaces are the preferred indentation method."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copied and pasted into my editor and the if on line 32 is indented for no reason:

```
def main():
    process_file("good_data.txt")
    process_file("bad_data.txt")
    process_file("empty_file.txt")
    process_file("does_not_exist.txt")

def process_file(param_str_file_name):
    #Variables
    num_rec = 0
    total = 0
    average = 0

    try:
        file_name = open(param_str_file_name, 'r')

        print("Processing file", param_str_file_name)

        one_score = file_name.readline()

        while one_score != "":
            one_score_int = int(one_score)
            num_rec = num_rec + 1

            one_score = file_name.readline()

            total += one_score_int
            average = total / num_rec

        file_name.close()

        if num_rec == 0:
            print("\tError!", param_str_file_name,
                  " is empty. Cannot calculate average\n")
        else:
            print("\tRecord count = ", num_rec)
            print("\tTotal        = ", total)
            print("\tAverage      = ", f"{average:.2f}", "\n")

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, " File not found\n")

    except ValueError:
        print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, "contains non-numeric data\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It should work now. The output I get is:

```
Processing file good_data.txt
    Record count =  6
    Total        =  281
    Average      =  46.83

Processing file bad_data.txt
    Error! bad_data.txt contains non-numeric data

Processing file empty_file.txt
    Error! empty_file.txt  is empty. Cannot calculate average

    Error! does_not_exist.txt  File not found
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @richardhead Great. You can mark my answer as accepted then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From what i saw in your code the "if" on line 32 is not indented well, and the rest of the lines aswell cause of the error on the "if".

If you are using Visual Studio code and other programs they usually have a shortcut to format the code, per example on Visual Studio code if you press "Alt+Shift+F" it formats the code.

U should search for "Format Code Shortcut for ...." for the software you are using.